# How to create NavMenu with collapsible submenu in .Net Core Blazor app

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to create a blazor navmenu which has a shape like this

- item a
- item b

when I click on item b it expands with sub menu like this and clicking on subitems, new pages open

- item a
- item b

  - subitem 1
  - subitem 2

I just edited the original blazor app but no success. The button appears but it doesn't collapse submenu. any idea?

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="@ToggleNavMenu">
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch Data
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">

        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="meeting">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Meetings
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="conference">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Conferences
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="event">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Events
                    </NavLink>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do not use the data-toggle and data-target for it.

These are used by boostrap.js however you do not want to modify the DOM in that way.

What you do instead is to use an if statement and thus let Blazor take care of the rendering:

```
    <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
    </NavLink>
    @if (expandSubNav)
    {
        <NavLink class="expand-menu" href="">
            <span>Sub1</span>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink class="" href="">
            <span>Sub2</span>
        </NavLink>
    }
```

And put the expandSubNav field into your code section:

```
@code {

    private bool expandSubNav;

}
```

Comment: This works well, it moves the other items  away to fit the new sub menu items, and if clicked again, removes sub menu and fills its place with other menu items. When I used syle="visibility:@visibilityString"  where visibilityString="Hidden"/"Visible". The sub menus become  appear/disappear but the menu items do not move.

Comment: This is nice, but after load, expandSubNav again is false and its collapsed :/

Comment: This answer is good, but it doesnt account for multiple submenus.

Comment: Just another note, I used this method and worked great. However, if you'd like your node to expand if a user navigates to a page manually, say from an external link, or typing into the address bar, you can inject NavigationManager, use it to check the Uri of the current page, and if it matches a page in your sub menu then set the expandSubNav to true, do this in the OnInitializedAsync override

Answer (score 8):

You can try this solution if you have more submenus

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">System</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu(navSubmenu)">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu(NavSubmenu.None)" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu.First)">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submenu 1
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (navSubmenu == NavSubmenu.First)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="counter">
                    <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch Data
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu.Second)">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submenu 2
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (navSubmenu == NavSubmenu.Second)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="counter">
                    <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch Data
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private enum NavSubmenu
    {
        None,
        First,
        Second
    }

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;
    private NavSubmenu navSubmenu =  NavSubmenu.None;
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;


    private void ToggleNavMenu(NavSubmenu? submenu = null)
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
        navSubmenu = submenu ?? navSubmenu;
    }

    private void TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu submenu)
    {
        if (navSubmenu == submenu)
            navSubmenu = NavSubmenu.None;
        else
            navSubmenu = submenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked fine when pasted into VS Blazor Server template app. Nice work.

Comment: This works perfectly but if you put more navlink in the menu the css of the side bar moves and the <li> go out of the margin of the sidebar, how could the problem be solved? I think it is caused by this: height: 100vh;

Answer (score 5):

My Solution, after problems with not closing on click the submenu:

[image]

works on Mobile:

[image]

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MyPrgramm</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu-II
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" @onclick="() => expandSubNavSettings = !expandSubNavSettings" id="navbarDropdown" >
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu III
                    </NavLink>
                    @if (expandSubNavSettings)
                    {
                        <li class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" @onclick="() => expandSubNavSettings = !expandSubNavSettings">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="fetchdata">
                                    <span class="oi oi-fork" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="counter">
                                    <span class="oi oi-command" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <NavLink class="nav-link text-dark" href="home">
                                    <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </li>
                    }
                </li>



            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

@code {

```
bool collapseNavMenu = true;

private bool expandSubNavSettings;


string baseMenuClass = "navbar-collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse";

string NavMenuCssClass => baseMenuClass + (collapseNavMenu ? " collapse" : "");

void ToggleNavMenu()
{
    if(!expandSubNavSettings)
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: This was the best answer for me, but the menu remains open if the mouse is clicked off of it(on empty space or a different link not in the dropdown). What would need to be done to have the SubNav menu collapse when the mouse is clicked off of it?

Comment: Nice Wolfgang. Thank you.
To solve the submenu stays open when you choose an item in the menu, add @onclick="() => expandSubNavSettings=false" into the Menu item (not the submenuitem) 

Example :
 <a class="navbar-brand" href=""
 @onclick="() => expandSubNavSettings=false" >MyPrgramm</a>

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
</div>
@if (expandSubNav)
{
    <NavLink class="expand-menu" href="">
        <span>Sub1</span>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink class="" href="">
        <span>Sub2</span>
    </NavLink>
}
```

use div instead of NAVLINK. Navlink reloads the page and reset the expandSubNav.

Comment: remove href="" for not reload page.

Comment: U made no effort this is a direct copy of the above answer.

Answer (score 4):

[(End result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoW58.png) I struggled quite a bit with submenus and ended up using this in my project:

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Submenu master</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>ToggleNavMenu()" href=""     Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>ToggleSubmenu()">
                <span class="oi oi-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        @if (expandMenu)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-4" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                    <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private bool expandMenu;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
        expandMenu = false;
    }

    private void ToggleSubmenu()
    {
        expandMenu = !expandMenu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Implement Sub-menu by using Bootstrap**

Default template of Blazor generate `collapse` class inside `@media` in `NavMenu.razor.css` which interferes with Bootstrap's submenu `collapse` so we need to rename it to something else.

```css
/* NavMenu.razor.css */
/* Add */
.sidebar-collapse {
    display: none;
}

/* Modify */
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    ...
    
    .sidebar-collapse { 
        /* Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens */
        display: block;
    }
}
```

On `NavMenu.razor` replace the same class name inside code block

```cs
/* NavMenu.razor */
private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "sidebar-collapse" : null;
```

Remove `@onclick="ToggleNavMenu"` from `nav` parent `div`

```html
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass">
   <nav class="flex-column">
      ...
   </nav>
</div>
```

Add Sub-Menu Items.
Classes `has-submenu`, `nav-submenu` and `nav-subitem` are optional but will be used for styling later

```html
<div class="nav-item has-submenu px-3">
   <NavLink class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userSubMenu"> <!-- <= this id -->
       <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Users
   </NavLink>
    <ul class="nav-submenu collapse list-unstyled" id="userSubMenu"> <!-- <= and this id must match -->
       <li class="nav-subitem">
           <NavLink href="users/add">
               <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add
           </NavLink>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-subitem">
           <NavLink href="users/list">
               <span class="oi oi-people" aria-hidden="true"></span> View
           </NavLink>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4.x**

Add js files in `index.html`

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Bootstrap 5.x**

Add js files in `index.html`

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

On `NavLink` Replace `data-toggle` with `data-bs-toggle` and `data-target` with `data-bs-target`

---

Sub-menu should be working now.

**Additional Styling**

Add these styles to `NavMenu.razor.css`

```css
/* Custom Styles */
.nav-item ::deep .nav-link i {
    width: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

::deep .nav-item.has-submenu > a {
    position: relative;
}

    ::deep .nav-item.has-submenu > a:after {
        content: "\e02f";
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Icons";
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 13px;
        transform: rotateZ(90deg);
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform .5s ease;
    }

    ::deep .nav-item.has-submenu > a.collapsed:after {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }

.nav-item ::deep .nav-submenu .nav-subitem a {
    padding-left: 3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    .nav-item ::deep .nav-submenu .nav-subitem a i {
        width: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
```

Comment: By far the best answer here, works great on .NET 6 Blazor project.

Comment: One thing I glazed over was the addition of the Bootstrap `.js` file as I was reading this answer and thought, "oh I already have the bootstrap.min.css file..." Click wasn't working as this is a bootstrap component and requires the .js file too. It's a well written answer just highlighting the difference. Also from a Blazor perspective this is something to weigh. You can do this same collapse functionality using a C# toggle variable wrapping the menu items. That might make more sense then having to add another JS library if that's all it's being used for.

Comment: Is there a way to disable an item by programming ?

Comment: Is there a way to keep the submenus open when I select an item?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to have perfect look of sub menu items, here is the example:

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="cart" @onclick="()=>expandSubMenu= !expandSubMenu">
                <span class="oi oi-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cart
            </NavLink>
            @if (expandSubMenu)
            {
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="cart/1">
                            <span class="oi oi-file" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sub-1
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="cart/2">
                            <span class="oi oi-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sub-1
                        </NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </li>
```

you also need to add expandSubMenu property to the code block

```
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private bool expandSubMenu;//add

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried you suggestion. It is fine but: I click on menu, it expands and immediately collapsed. What to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the same css class available in nav menu and made the submenu looks better.

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
<nav class="flex-column">
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
        </NavLink>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav=!expandSubNav">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Admin
        </NavLink>
        @if (expandSubNav)
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="device">
                    <span class="oi oi-arrow-circle-right"></span>Sub-menu 1
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                    <span class="oi oi-arrow-circle-right"></span>Sub-menu 2
                </NavLink>
            </div>

        }
    </div>        
</nav>
```

```
@code {
private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
private bool expandSubNav = false;

private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

private void ToggleNavMenu()
{
    collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I took a approach with jQuery and also made the menu responsive :

[image: Sample menu]

A complete sample can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/stephandeckers/ResponsiveBlazorApp1)

Comment: Please share the pertinent code as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was not happy with the solutions so after a lot of thinking I came up with the following one. This does work on normal browser and mobile.

**For browser:**

1. Submenu only collapse after a click on it.
2. Submenu collapse after the click on the title (Webassembly).
3. Submenus did not collapse if some other sections are clicked.

**For mobile:**

1. Page starts with Navmenu collapsed
2. Submenu only collapses after click on it.
3. Navmenu did collapse after selection (if not the submenu is collapsed by it)
4. Navmenu collapses after click on the title (Webassembly).

The trick was to remove the NavMenuToggle in the `<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable ...">` element to get more control over the each element inside the div. I also changed some of the variables to make more sense for me.

Here is the full code:

```cs
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid" @onclick="CloseEveryMenu">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WebAssembly</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClassCollapse nav-scrollable">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="ToggleSubMenu">
                <span class="oi" aria-hidden="true">Configuration</span>
            </NavLink>
            @if (subMenuExpanded)
            {
                <div class="nav-item px-3" @onclick="CloseNavMenu">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <span class="oi oi-arrow-circle-right"></span>Sub-menu 1
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item px-3" @onclick="CloseNavMenu">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <span class="oi oi-arrow-circle-right"></span>Sub-menu 2
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool navMenuExpanded = false;
    private bool subMenuExpanded = false;

    private string? NavMenuCssClassCollapse => navMenuExpanded ? null : "collapse";

    private void ToggleNavMenu() => navMenuExpanded = !navMenuExpanded;
    private void ToggleSubMenu() => subMenuExpanded = !subMenuExpanded;

    private void CloseNavMenu() => navMenuExpanded = false;
    private void CloseSubMenu() => subMenuExpanded = false;

    private void CloseEveryMenu()
    {
        CloseSubMenu();
        ToggleNavMenu();
    }
}
```